# Google maps event problem with flex actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, google-maps, events

I am able to render a google map on a flex canvas.  I create the map using the code below and then place markers on it in the onMapReady method (not shown)

```
var map:com.google.maps.Map=new com.google.maps.Map();
map.id="map";
map.key="bla bla";
_mapCanvas.addChild(map);
map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY,onMapReady);
```

It all works fine.  However, if I remove the map and then set _mapCanvas to null, then run exactly the same code again, the onMapReady event does not fire.  It is weird, but once a  map has been created and deleted, the onMapReady event never seems to fire again.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this was happening, but I worked around the issue by creating the map as an application-level variable, only instantiating it once, and then adding and removing it from canvases as required.  Not ideal, but at least I can now display and remove a map dynamically, even if it exists in memory between invocations.